Directly computing dimension of $M_P/M_P^2$
Consider the variety $V_1\colon Y^2=X^3$ in $\mathbb{A}^2$. By the Jacobian matrix it is easy to see that this variety has a singularity at $P=(0,0)$. This means that $M_P/M_P^2=\frac{\langle\bar X,\bar Y\rangle}{\langle\bar X^2,\bar Y^2,\bar X\bar Y\rangle}$ considered as a $\bar K$-vector space must have dimension more than one. $\{\bar X, \bar Y\}$ evidently spans $M_P/M_P^2$. So I need to show that its elements are linearly independent, i.e. if $a\bar X + b\bar Y=0$ then $a=b=0$. Given that there are two ideals in the denominator which every term is computer modulo them I'm not sure how I should proceed.
The precise thing that I need some help with is how to argue about dimension given both the ideal that determines the variety and $M_P^2$ being identified with zero. Also, I know there are workarounds with doing this computations but I want to compute the dimension directly.

About significance of $M/M^2$ see for example here.

@JeanMarie Thanks for the pointer but my question is not about significance. I want to know how to compute the dimension.

This comment was directed towards readers who meet this "mathematical beeing" for the first time.

@JeanMarie Aha, thanks!

The dimension is certainly no more than $2$. Any element of $\langle\overline{X},\overline{Y}\rangle$ is some residue class of $f(X,Y)X+g(X,Y)Y$ and the relations $X^2=XY=Y^2=0$ mean all higher order terms disappear; only the constant terms of $f$ and $g$ survive once multiplied by $X,Y$ respectively and we just have some combination $aX+bY$, $a=f(0,0),b=g(0,0)$. So $\overline{X},\overline{Y}$ span the quotient $\mathfrak{m}_p/\mathfrak{m}^2_p$ over the ground ring $k$ nevermind over the residue field. From the Jacobian criterion you know the dimension then must be $2$. But concretely, our task would be to show $\overline{X},\overline{Y}$ are linearly independent over the residue field $(k[X,Y]/(Y^2-X^3))_p/\mathfrak{m}_p$. If we work with a field $k$ this is just $\mathrm{Frac}(k[X,Y]/(X,Y,Y^2-X^3))\cong k$, and clearly no $a\overline{X}+b\overline{Y}$ can be zero for scalars $a,b$ in $k$ for degree reasons, this couldn't be a multiple of $X^2,Y^2$ or $XY$. Thus the dimension is $2$.
